# Dot product over upper matrix and matrix of units

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices

Does there exist a dot product on space of matrix nxn (n>1) regarding to which the matrix of all units would be orthogonal to any
upper triangular matrix?

First i thought to define dot product as 
$$(A,B) = \sum_{i,j=1}^n \hat \delta_{i,j} a_{i,j} b_{i,j}$$
where
$$
\hat \delta_{i,j} =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $i\le i$} \\
0, & \text{if $i \gt j$}
\end{cases}
$$

But when I try to prove that this IS a product dot there is a mistake: $(A,A)$ gives zero so my formula is not really a product dot. Any ideas how to find correct one please?

Comment: What is the matrix of all units?

Comment: $$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1& ... & 1 \\ 
1 &1 & ... &1 \\
... & ... & ... & ...\\
1 &1 & ... &1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$